# How to dispose unmanaged resources in an async way?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asynchronous, dispose

Is it possible to call the dispose() of unmanaged resources in a new thread without waiting for the result?
I have an async function that is using 2 unmanaged resources. (rdKafka producer and topic). After some testing and time stamp measuring, i realized that their Dispose function is taken a long time to finish, so i would like to call the dispose() of those resources in a different thread and not to "await" for his result. 
Meaning, i would like to get the result as soon as possible and let some thread handle the dispose() whenever.

Here is my code:

```
public async Task<bool> ProduceMessage(object someobject)
    {
        var result = true;
        using (var producer = new Producer(_kafkaOptions.Uri)) {
            using (var topic = producer.Topic(_kafkaOptions.Topic, topicConfig)) {
                var report = topic.Produce(someobject);
                await report.ContinueWith(task =>
                {
                    if (task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion) {
                        //if produce succeed and task completed, return true
                        _logger.LogDebug("Producer Succeed");
                        result = true;
                    } else {
                        HandleError(task);
                        result = false;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but you should never mix async/await with `ContinueWith` it leads to many bugs.  [You should just do `await report` and have the code in the `ContinueWith` be after it](https://gist.github.com/leftler/2767460d2aa135aa80c9b123e517b51b). Also please update your question to show the rest of the method, it will help us form answers.

Comment: Sorry about that, i'm new here :) thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

Don't put them in a `using` statement. Instead, do a `try/finally` block and call `Task.Run(() => producer.Dispose);` etc. in the `finally` portion. You won't need to await the `Dispose` calls assuming that they never throw an exception, but you probably should for unit testing purposes. If it's worth waiting for the success logging, it's worth waiting for the dispose calls as well. The goal is to be able to do a lot of these `ProduceMessage` calls in parallel (and then wait for them as a batch).

There is some chance that your `Dispose` calls are doing a disk or socket flush. You may want to wait for them in a shutdown scenario. Another option would be to do the socket flush in the `Produce` call. That way your success logging would be more truthful.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the `Dispose` to occur in the caller thread, just execute it in a continuation. The only annoying part is making sure the topic is disposed if `producer.Topic(_kafkaOptions.Topic, topicConfig)` throws an exception.

```
private async Task<bool> DoProduce(Topic topic, object someObject)
{
    try
    {
        var report = await topic.Produce(someObject);
        _logger.LogDebug("Producer Succeed");
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HandleError(ex);
        return false;
    }
}

public Task<bool> ProduceAsync(object someObject)
{
    var producer = new Producer(_kafkaOptions.Uri);

    Topic topic = null;

    try
    {
        topic = producer.Topic(_kafkaOptions.Topic, topicConfig);
    }
    finally
    {
        producer.Dispose();                
    }

    var task = DoProduce(topic, someObject);

    task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        topic.Dispose();
        producer.Dispose();
    }, TaskScheduler.Default);

    return task;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If what you want is control over disposal of resources, It sounds to me like you should be injecting the resources into the method.

That would take the responsibility of [creating them and] disposing of them away from the method and allow it to complete in a timely manner. You can then decide how you destroy the resources separately.

Comment: If you are going to downvote something, the polite thing to do is make a comment as to why you feel something is not a good idea so that everyone can benefit and chip in.

Comment: You were probably downvoted because this does not answer the question.  This is a comment and should have been posted as one.  (I am not the downvoter, by the way).

Comment: Thank you @ChrisDunaway, although I respectfully disagree. It is a solution that would solve the problem. I can certainly expand the solution if needed. That being said, the downvoter should still take the time to comment to avoid people having to waste their time trying to figure out why he/she did.